# Why does my /setblock command not work?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

```
/setblock ~ 1 ~ lapis_ore
```

that command doesn't seem to place the ore. i have also tried

```
/setblock ~ 1 ~ lapis_lazuli_ore
```

And it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

`lapis_ore` is correct according to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore#ID). It's probably something to do with your setup, and I can hazard a guess to your problem.

The coordinates `~ 1 ~` means to use your X and Z, but use Y level 1, which is at the bottom of your world. You may have actually meant to use `~ ~1 ~` which means "my Y level plus 1", instead of actually using the Y level 1.